# Dynamic Typing a Generic Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an object that's being automatically serialized by the WebAPI, but I wanted to wrap it to provide context to my data.  An example would be:

```
public class SecureModel<T>
{
  public string Info { get; set; }
  public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

This serializes/deserializes no problem with my JSON requests and all is well.  However, I want to verify some of that Info before I allow the request to finish executing, so I've added an ActionFilter where I'm retrieving parameters of my POST.

```
public class MyAuth : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
    var arg = actionContext.ActionArguments.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    // arg: get the Info?
    // if the info isn't correct, return a specific Response.
  }
}
```

When I examine the argument, it's exactly what I need, however I can't figure out how to weakly type it to SecureModel without specifying the *actual* generic type. I feel like I should be able to case this to SecureModel<object> and properly access the root, however it does not allow that.  So far, I can only get the data I need using:

```
var notStrongEnough = arg.GetType().GetProperty("Info");
```

However, I'd prefer not to use Reflection for this and I am having a hard time moving forward without an answer.  My alternative in this situation would be to change Data to a string and serialize/deserialize the JSON object manually, but that defeats some of the purpose of using Web API over MVC3.

**Note:**  Changing the design to have SecureModel as the base class adds challenges to some of the hashing I am performing on the data, so I'd prefer to not go down that path either.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Misphrased title.

Comment: Why not to try dynamic arg = actionContext.ActionArguments.FirstOrDefault().Value

Comment: In C#, there are generics, but not templates. Those are different programming models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical solution to this sort of problem in C# is to create non-generic interfaces that your generic types implement.  For example, with your class:

```
public class SecureModel<T>
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

You could define an interface, `ISecureModel`:

```
public interface ISecureModel 
{
    string Info { get; }
    object Data { get; }
}
```

And now you can implement it in your data class:

```
public class SecureModel<T> : ISecureModel
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }

    object ISecureModel.Data {
        get { return Data; }
    }
}
```

We use explicit interface implementation here since the non-generic (`object`) and generic (`T`) versions of property `Data` would otherwise collide.

Now, to get the info, you can simply cast to `ISecureModel`.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to propose :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would opt for creating separate untyped interface and implementing it:

```
interface IObjectTypeSercureModel
{
    object GetData();
    string GetInfo();
}
```

However, It you can split getters and setters into separate interfaces, it would be possible to use C# template [co-variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) feature:

```
public interface IReadModel<out T>
{
    T Data {get;}
    string Info { get; }
}
public interface IWriteModel<in T>
{
    T Data { set; }
    string Info { set; }
}
public class SecureModel<T> : IReadModel<T>, IWriteModel<T>
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new SecureModel<string>();
        m.Data = "test";

        IReadModel<object> genericRead = (IReadModel<object>)m;
        Console.WriteLine(genericRead.Data);
    }
}
```